# Ionic Framework (angularjs) cannot POST to spring-social-facebook

Tags: spring-boot, ionic-framework, spring-social-facebook

I am using Ionic Framework to implement a social app for the Front-End (hybrid Android and iOS).  For the back-end I am using spring boot with hibernate.  I am trying to pull content from Facebook by using spring-social-facebook; however, I am having problems submitting a POST to back-end with spring-social-facebook

## Front-End

In services.js I am using the following source code to POST

.factory('springFB', ['$resource', '$rootScope',
  function($resource, $rootScope){
    return $resource($rootScope.clhost + $rootScope.clport + '/connect/facebook/', {}, {
      query: {method:'POST', params:{}, isArray:false}
    });
  }])

In html file I am using the following AngularJS form:

```
        <form action="/connect/facebook" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="scope" value=" public_profile, email, user_friends, user_posts, user_photos, user_videos" />
            <div class="formInfo">
                <p>You aren't connected to Facebook yet. Click the button to connect Mote with your Facebook account.</p>
            </div>
            <p><button type="submit"><img src="/resources/social/facebook/connect_light_medium_short.png"/></button>      </p>
        </form>
```

I get

## Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Oct 20 02:23:45 UTC 2015There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).Request method 'GET' not supported

On the back-end I have several facebook controllers, the redirect is setup to localhost:8100 and AWS EC2 where the spring boot jar is running in the facebook app, the spring boot .jar file is running in AWS EC2.

I am not sure what I am missing

Comment: I am also getting a Facebook Graph API error https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=<clientID>&respon

The parameter redirect_uri is required

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am going to try to add parameters to the POST HTTP Request in the Header

Comment: I did not.  Moved the logic for facebook authentication/consent from server-side as described above to the client-side (Ionic with JavaScript) using the fb ionic authentication provider, no I get the token pass it to the server-side; however, the facebook login screen comes up but after successfully authentication with facebook the fb consent page does not come up

I am using

$ionicAuth.login('facebook',['public_profile','email,user_friends','user_posts','user_photos','user_videos']).then(function(response){

I don't think the ionic facebook provider allows you to use scope

.

Comment: I tried with apache cordova and I get the same results